# SwiftUI: How can I customize the sheet only for iPad?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I´m new in SwiftUI and I have the following problem. When I click the button on the iPhone the following comes up

[image]

but when I press the button on the iPad the following comes up

[image]

The picker is not on the whole sheet. How can I show the picker on the iPad on the whole sheet like on the iPhone?

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State var value_2 = 1
    @State var show_1 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.show_1.toggle()
            }) {
                    Text("Push")
                }
            .sheet(isPresented: $show_1) {
                Sheet(show_0: self.$show_1, value_1: self.$value_2)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Sheet: View {
    @Binding var show_0: Bool
    @Binding var value_1: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            number(value_0: $value_1)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Enter number"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                    self.show_0 = false
                }) {
                    Text("Done").bold()
            })
        }
    }
}

struct number: View {
    @Binding var value_0: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            Text("Headline")
            Picker("",selection: $value_0)
                    {
                        ForEach(1..<101) { value in
                            Text("\(value)")
                }
            }
        }
        .labelsHidden()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood your intention, you need just change a style of navigation view, like

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        number(value_0: $value_1)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Enter number"), displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
                self.show_0 = false
            }) {
                Text("Done").bold()
        })
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())    // << here !!
}
```